# Getting the name of Ruby method for a literal hash query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, hash

In a rails application, I have a number of attributes for a model called Record. I want to design a method that when called on an attribute, returns the name of the attribute (which is essentially a method on the Record object). This name is then passed to an Hash, which returns a number (for the sake of this example, say the number is a percentage which is then multiplied by the original attribute value to get a `new value`).

For example, say my Record has four attributes: `teachers`, `students`, `principals`, and `parents`. The method would then look like the following:

```
def name
  **something here**
end
```

and the corresponding `new_value` method and `PRECENTAGE` hash would look like this:

```
def new_value
  self * PERCENTAGE[self.name]
end

PERCENTAGE = {
  "teachers"   => 0.40,
  "students"   => 0.53,
  "principals" => 0.21,
  "parents"    => 0.87
}
```

Then, to execute this whole thing, I would do `Record.students.new_value`, which would return new number of students according to the percentage obtained in the hash.

I know that to get the name of a method that is currently executing, you can do something like this: (found on http://ryat.la/7RDk)

```
def this_method
  __method__
end
```

but that won't work for me, because I need the name of the *previously* executed method.

If you have any suggestions as to an alternative approach to accomplishing my goal, I'd be happy to try something else.

Comment: Can you post an example of what your intended method call would look like?  The confusing part (to me) is where you say you call a method on an attribute.  Do you mean `Record.students.some_method` or `some_method(Record.students)`?  Or something else?

Comment: In the code above, I use the former, and pass self to the hash. The example would look like `Record.students.new_value` which would return `self * PERCENTAGE[self.name]`. The latter option would work too though. (question edited – sorry for the confusion!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan, I'm struggling to understand your question, but I think this is what you want, for `record.teachers_percent`, for example:

```
["teachers", "students", "principals", "parents"].each do |attrib|
  Record.class_eval <<-RUBY
    def #{attrib}_percent
      #{attrib} * PERCENTAGE[#{attrib.inspect}]
    end
  RUBY
end
```

Although this is probably a cleaner solution, giving `record.percent(:teachers)` or `record.percent("teachers")`:

```
class Record
  def percent(attrib)
    self.send(attrib) * PERCENTAGE[attrib.to_s]
  end
end
```

Comment: The second is definitely the way to go – that does exactly what I want. Thanks Ben!